# how do i remove the " , '()" symbols from the dropdown box?

Tags: python, tkinter, search

I am retrieving data from SQLite to then be added in a dropdown list but some of the options contain symbols like [(.') and a few others what I have noticed is the first item and the last item are the ones that contain these symbols but idk how to remove them

Here is a picture of what I mean:

[not all the options contain it and some have different symbols]

![1]

and this is my code for it:

```
def Search_Ingredients():
    search_ingredients = Tk()

    con = sqlite3.connect("Food.db")
    c = con.cursor()

    c.execute("SELECT Ingredients FROM Dinner_Stove")
    stove = c.fetchall()
    c.execute("SELECT Ingredients FROM Dinner_Oven")
    oven = c.fetchall()
    c.execute("SELECT Ingredients FROM Dinner_Cold")
    cold = c.fetchall()
    c.execute("SELECT Ingredients FROM Dinner_Simple")
    simple = c.fetchall()
    con.commit()

    ingredients = stove + oven + cold + simple
    ingredient = (str(ingredients).lower().split(", "))
    mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(ingredient))



    search_ingredients.title("Python Guides")
    search_ingredients.geometry("350x300")

    def search_items():
         c.execute("""SELECT * 
         FROM Dinner_Cold AND Dinner_Oven AND Dinner_Stove AND Dinner_simple 
         WHERE Ingredients = (?)""", combo1.get() or combo2.get() or combo3.get() or combo4.get())

    label1 = Label(search_ingredients,
                   text="What Can You Find At Home?: ",
                   font=("Times New Roman", 10),
                   padx=10, pady=10)
    label1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

    combo1 = Combobox(search_ingredients, state='readonly')
    combo1['values'] = mylist
    combo1.grid(row=0, column=3)

    label2 = Label(search_ingredients,
                   text="What Can You Find At Home?: ",
                   font=("Times New Roman", 10),
                   padx=10, pady=10)
    label2.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

    combo2 = Combobox(search_ingredients, state='readonly')
    combo2['values'] = ingredients
    combo2.grid(row=1, column=3)

    label3 = Label(search_ingredients,
                   text="What Can You Find At Home?: ",
                   font=("Times New Roman", 10),
                   padx=10, pady=10)
    label3.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

    combo3 = Combobox(search_ingredients, state='readonly')
    combo3['values'] = ingredients
    combo3.grid(row=2, column=3)

    label4 = Label(search_ingredients,
                   text="What Can You Find At Home?: ",
                   font=("Times New Roman", 10),
                   padx=10, pady=10)
    label4.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

    combo4 = Combobox(search_ingredients, state='readonly')
    combo4['values'] = ingredients
    combo4.grid(row=3, column=3)

    button = Button(search_ingredients,font=("Times New Roman", 16), text="More Ingredients",width=13, command=search_items)
    button.grid(row=4, column=0)

    button = Button(search_ingredients,font=("Times New Roman", 16), text="Search",width=10, command=search_items)
    button.grid(row=4, column=3)
```

Comment: You need to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). All the Tkinter stuff is almost certainly unnecessary.

Comment: If you are going to treat every query as a string and add them together, then you are going to run into problems. There are better ways to read records in sqlite which will return the raw data and make your life easier.

Comment: Are your items already like that in your database? it looks a bit like data that wasn't inserted correctly

Comment: @jjramsey last time i asked a question i gave minimal code but that was the problem now i gave the whole code of my problem ( my program atm is 540 lines so i only gave the part im having problems with and now thats the problem? how should i give my code so i get help instead of people telling me to give more or less code?

Comment: @Peter im still new the programming so if theres a better way im all ears/eyes

Comment: @Talon im using SQlite database and it has a database browser and using this browser is how i added all my items i went through a long proccess before i was able to get it to look like the way it is it originaly gave every ingredient that was under 1 item as 1 choice so for example cheese,milk,bread was 1 choice instead of 3 differnt choices

Comment: @ZFV6 There are tons of tutorials on how to correctly use sqlite in Python, personally I use `SQLALchemy` to wrap it so I don't know the syntax you want off the top of my head.

Comment: @Peter thank you il look into SQALchemy i got suggested a realy good one that needs user name and password inside the code to be able to access the database but i didnt like that one coz if i was to give my program to another person so they can use it as well the couldnt access the database so i went with a simplier database thats how i coudn this one

Comment: The SQL statement in the `search_item` function makes no sense. Maybe it makes sense for you, but not for a SQL database.

Comment: @Matthias what do you suggest?

Comment: Maybe you could use `UNION` because `FROM Dinner_Cold AND Dinner_Oven AND Dinner_Stove AND Dinner_simple` is not valid SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This part might be a reason for the problem

```
ingredients = stove + oven + cold + simple
ingredient = (str(ingredients).lower().split(", "))
mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(ingredient))
```

Handling strings like this can introduce errors easily.

I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve with the `dict.fromkeys`, it seems like you want a list of unique ingredients?

```py
ingredients = stove + oven + cold + simple
distinct_ingredients = list({ingredient[0].lower() for ingredient in ingredients}})
```

I'm using a set comprehension here turn the list into a set, which eliminates duplicates. That might be what you wanted to do with the dictionary keys.

#### Edit for comment

`my_list = list(dict.fromkeys(ingredient))` will not remove any symbols, it just turns your list into a dictionary where every ingredient is a key and every value is None, and then with `list(...)` you take only the keys and discard the values.

When i follow your program with dummy data step by step, it will look like this:

```py
c.execute("SELECT Ingredients FROM Dinner_Stove")
stove = c.fetchall()
c.execute("SELECT Ingredients FROM Dinner_Oven")
oven = c.fetchall()
c.execute("SELECT Ingredients FROM Dinner_Cold")
cold = c.fetchall()
c.execute("SELECT Ingredients FROM Dinner_Simple")
simple = c.fetchall()

ingredients = stove + oven + cold + simple
ingredient = (str(ingredients).lower().split(", "))
mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(ingredient))

>>> ingredients
[('ab',), ('cd',), ('cd',), ('xz',), ('ef',), ('zy',), ('gh',), ('mn',)]

>>> ingredient
["[('ab',)",
 "('cd',)",
 "('cd',)",
 "('xz',)",
 "('ef',)",
 "('zy',)",
 "('gh',)",
 "('mn',)]"]

>>> mylist
["[('ab',)", "('cd',)", "('xz',)", "('ef',)", "('zy',)", "('gh',)", "('mn',)]"]

# With the line for distinct_ingredients:
>>> list({ingredient[0].lower() for ingredient in ingredients if}})  
['zy', 'ef', 'mn', 'xz', 'ab', 'cd', 'gh']
```

When I now add simplified tkinter:

```py
distinct_ingredients = list({ingredient[0].lower() for ingredient in ingredients}})
root = Tk()
combo1 = Combobox(root, state='readonly')
combo1['values'] = distinct_ingredients
combo1.grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Then I get the desired result of the dropdown list where every entry is a single ingredient without symbols.

When there are `Null`-values in the database, SQLite gives you `None`, so you might want to filter these out:

```
list({ingredient[0].lower() for ingredient in ingredients if ingredient[0] is not None}})
```

#### Edit

Putting the comments together:

```py
cleaned = [ingredient[0] for ingredient in ingredients if ingredient[0] is not None]
isolated = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable([group.split(", ") for group in cleaned]))
alphabetical = sorted(isolated)  # optional
```

Comment: yes i was trying do remove the duplicates i had a question about it earlier and someone suggested sets but i wasnt able to use sets couldnt figure it out and then i searched google for removing duplicates and it came up with what i have in my code at the moment but with or without the dict.fromkeys the symbols are still there how can i get rid of em?

Comment: @ZFV6 I have made an edit where i try to isolate that and follow it. (Side-point: you use `mylist` only on the first combobox, the others use `ingredients`)

Comment: i know that only the first one uses mylist while the resr is ingredients ( i was just trying to make it work the way i want it to before changeing the rest ( i created the other comboboxes before the ingredients started working the way i wanted it to so instead of changing all of them every time i was playing around with only 1 and when i get it working il change all of them

Comment: i dont know if i am using ur code distinct_ingredients = list({ingredient[0].lower() for ingredient in ingredients}) correctly but when i added it to my code i got the following error File "C:\Users\thatm\PycharmProjects\myownProjects\what should i eat.py", line 416, in <setcomp>
    distinct_ingredients = list({ingredient[0].lower() for ingredient in ingredients})
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: @ZFV6 you seem to have null-values in your tatabase then; try thins: `list({ingredient[0].lower() for ingredient in ingredients if ingredient[0] is not None})` (I'll also make an edit)

Comment: it ALMOST works perfectly i cant see any symbols in it how ever the ingredients are grouped together instead of being seprate for example one of my items is potato casserole with the ingredients " potato, Eggs, Sausage, Sour Cream, Pork Fat," unfurtatatly the drop down box shows this as 1 option instead of 5 differnt options ( thats why i was using split) and then i need to remove all the dublicates after all of them are split up is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Aaaaah so your tables have a column with a dish and a second column with all the ingredients together. Okay, if you are sure about the comma separations, you can do something like this: `import itertools` `set(itertools.chain.from_iterable([group.split(", ") for group in ingredients]))`. `itertools.chain.from_iterable` can unnest nested lists, so it turns `[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]` into `[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]`. Then, with `set()` we can discard duplicates. You might then put that into `sorted()` to not get randomly sorted ingredients

Comment: If you want to have a more "stable" solution in a future project, you could look into ways to either save lists into a table or normalize the table layout

Comment: thank you for your help il try to add ur new code to my code hope it works is there away i could contact you? i would like to show you my whole project and explain what it is and maybe help me simplify my code or maybe help me if i get stuck?

Comment: this is the error message i receive 

  File "C:\Users\thatm\PycharmProjects\myownProjects\what should i eat.py", line 418, in <listcomp>
    a = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable([group.split(", ") for group in ingredients])).itertools.chain.from_iterable
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: I made another edit with how that line fits into your usecase

Comment: thank you works exactly the way i wanted it to :D its perfect now i just need to figure out the search button and the add more ingredients button how to get those to work :S

Comment: would it be ok if i asked you for more help?